# SharePoint Online - Add a site footer

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, footer

As stated here : [Change the look of your SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818), it is possible to add a site footer to your SharePoint Online site.

The problem is: I can't find the "Footer" section in the "Change the look" option. I've tried on both Team sites and Communication sites and I'm the owner of the sites.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Communication sites have an out-of-the box footer control, which can be controlled either using UI elements or by using APIs.
More information:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/site-footer

Or you can refer to the methods provided in this link:
https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000258742-getting-started-with-shortpoint-footer-for-sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for adding footer from OOTB settings in SharePoint online.

However, you can use **Application Customizer** extensions in SharePoint Online for such kind of requirements.

You can find the detailed example on how to add footer to your SharePoint site using Application Customizer in below article:

[Use page placeholders from Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions).

To read more about extensions in SharePoint online, check below documentation by Microsoft:

[Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ganesh,it is not available OOTB only way is to do using SPFx extension.

I have created this reusable solution which will provide you user interface via webpart to add header and/or footer on SharePoint online modern pages. Please refer below link, you will get documentation on how to deploy/install and use this solution.

https://github.com/siddharth-vaghasia/SPFxWPConfigurableHeaderFooter